# product to tackle problem of senior citizens of our society who forget to take pills due to Memory Loss

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanisms

For a lot of senior citizens of our society, taking medications is a necessity.
Although necessary,it can be tedious sometimes. More often, these
patients forget to take pills due to Memory Loss. **Is there any product to tackle this
problem or any such product can be designed?**, Please suggest your valuable suggestion, Thanks

Comment: out of curiosity, why the structural engineering tag?

Comment: Amazon has hundreds to choose from - [pill minder](https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Health-Personal-Care-Pill-Dispensers-Reminders/zgbs/hpc/3776431/ref=zg_bs_pg_1?_encoding=UTF8&pg=1)

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Novel Idea' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/1832). Such questions tend to become moving targets and lead to discussions, neither of which are a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 2):

In college I was in a group that actually attempted to solve this exact issue for a design class. A pill dispenser with different reservoirs for each medication and an arduino programmed to dispense set quantities of each pill at specified times with a loud alarm that is impossible to ignore. The challenge is in mechanically dispensing individual pills of varying geometry. Overall the system is pretty cheap, our prototype maybe cost $50.

Comment: Thanks great to know your experience, sir when( year) did you designed your prototype ? May you please attach a sample image, if possible. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: That was in 2008, all the work was lost many hard drives ago. It should be pretty easy to recreate based on my answer already if there isn't an already existing product.

Comment: They do exist, had you done a thorough patent search you would have found several ways to solve your problem listed in the patent database even back in 2008. Hell, apothekaries in european countries have a service to prepack pills in dispenser rolls where you can dispense them from even without a arduino. (Cost is really low and its robotically handled). This is a very mature market